# How can I write a custom FXCop rule to check for conditional compilation symbols?

Tags: c#, fxcop

Can anyone advise me on how I would write an FXCop rule that checks for specific conditional compilation symbols?

If, for instance, I wanted to write an FXCop rule that checked that code has been compiled with the compilation symbol "CODE_ANALYSIS" defined, how would I go about doing that?

The only way that I can think of is to parse the .csproj file and look for . I think this way would become messy quickly as you would have to determine which of the build conditions were met for the current build. Any other suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can, as FxCop works on compiled code and once compiled code is produced, any notion of compilation symbols is removed (as the compiler uses them to produced compiled code, but they aren't in it).

Only thing i think you could do is have some code within a `CODE_ANALYSIS` symbol, then check for its existence in FxCop.

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought. I wonder if there is anyway of creating something like an attribute that will get injected pre-build, then I could look for that. I suppose I should look into doing this with MSBuild.

Comment: Like i say, just put something between an `#if CODE_ANALYSIS` section, then look for it in FxCop.

Comment: For my purpose I'd have to have the code injected in all projects using some sort of extension. As I'd have to write a VS extension I might as well just look for the appropriate constants before build in an extension.